# how to use Disqus JS api?

Tags: javascript, disqus

I get the `post id` like "342956146212" by the api of "https://disqus.com/api/3.0/posts/list.json".

It's successful.

I try to update the post as follows.

```
var forum = "portoxxxx";
var APIKEY = "r1GglbTmZuZLWl6xxxxxxyIBRtJNZf7SL";
jQuery.post('https://disqus.com/api/3.0/posts/update.json',{
        forum:forum,
        post:342956146212,
        message:"This comment has been overwritten",
        api_key:APIKEY})    });
```

but it's wrong.
[image]

please tell me how to finish it, thanks!

Comment: I don't know Disqus API but the error describes an unauthorized request. Is your API key valid ? And do you have the right permissions to update the post ? There must be a read/write permission somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved.

```
    jQuery.post('https://disqus.com/api/3.0/posts/update.json',{
        post:"2957858030",
        access_token:ACCESS_TOKEN,
        message:"This comment has been overwritten",
        api_key:APIKEY})
```

the previous argument of `forum` is invalid.

And I add the new argument of `access_token` to solve the authorized problem

Comment: Is this the solution to your problem? Stack Overflow is not a forum. Please do not use answers as replies.